# resize static table View Cell with device changes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i'm using static cell in a tableview controller .i've used custom height for each static cells. and it's fine in iphone Xs. but in smaller iphone i need the height change into smaller . how to do that ?

Comment: use Height Multiplier constraints.

Answer (score -1):

You can either:

1. Override / Implement `heightForRow` of the tableView delegate method.
2. OR if you're using `UITableView.automaticDimension`, you can of course adjust the constraints of the subviews of your cell.

And there are lots of ways to determine the type of iPhone the user currently has. You can determine the bounds (or height) of the current device, or use this long enum (I got this from somewhere here on Stackoverflow).

Sample usage:

```
if UIDevice().type == .iPhone5 {

}
```

**DeviceModel.swift**

```
public enum DeviceModel : String {
    case simulator     = "simulator/sandbox",
    //iPod
    iPod1              = "iPod 1",
    iPod2              = "iPod 2",
    iPod3              = "iPod 3",
    iPod4              = "iPod 4",
    iPod5              = "iPod 5",
    //iPad
    iPad2              = "iPad 2",
    iPad3              = "iPad 3",
    iPad4              = "iPad 4",
    iPadAir            = "iPad Air ",
    iPadAir2           = "iPad Air 2",
    iPad5              = "iPad 5", //aka iPad 2017
    iPad6              = "iPad 6", //aka iPad 2018
    //iPad mini
    iPadMini           = "iPad Mini",
    iPadMini2          = "iPad Mini 2",
    iPadMini3          = "iPad Mini 3",
    iPadMini4          = "iPad Mini 4",
    //iPad pro
    iPadPro9_7         = "iPad Pro 9.7\"",
    iPadPro10_5        = "iPad Pro 10.5\"",
    iPadPro12_9        = "iPad Pro 12.9\"",
    iPadPro2_12_9      = "iPad Pro 2 12.9\"",
    //iPhone
    iPhone4            = "iPhone 4",
    iPhone4S           = "iPhone 4S",
    iPhone5            = "iPhone 5",
    iPhone5S           = "iPhone 5S",
    iPhone5C           = "iPhone 5C",
    iPhone6            = "iPhone 6",
    iPhone6plus        = "iPhone 6 Plus",
    iPhone6S           = "iPhone 6S",
    iPhone6Splus       = "iPhone 6S Plus",
    iPhoneSE           = "iPhone SE",
    iPhone7            = "iPhone 7",
    iPhone7plus        = "iPhone 7 Plus",
    iPhone8            = "iPhone 8",
    iPhone8plus        = "iPhone 8 Plus",
    iPhoneX            = "iPhone X",
    iPhoneXS           = "iPhone XS",
    iPhoneXSMax        = "iPhone XS Max",
    iPhoneXR           = "iPhone XR",
    //Apple TV
    AppleTV            = "Apple TV",
    AppleTV_4K         = "Apple TV 4K",
    unrecognized       = "?unrecognized?"
}

// #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#
//MARK: UIDevice extensions
// #-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#

public extension UIDevice {
    public var type: DeviceModel {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let modelCode = withUnsafePointer(to: &systemInfo.machine) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: 1) {
                ptr in String.init(validatingUTF8: ptr)

            }
        }
        var modelMap : [ String : DeviceModel ] = [
            "i386"      : .simulator,
            "x86_64"    : .simulator,
            //iPod
            "iPod1,1"   : .iPod1,
            "iPod2,1"   : .iPod2,
            "iPod3,1"   : .iPod3,
            "iPod4,1"   : .iPod4,
            "iPod5,1"   : .iPod5,
            //iPad
            "iPad2,1"   : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,2"   : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,3"   : .iPad2,
            "iPad2,4"   : .iPad2,
            "iPad3,1"   : .iPad3,
            "iPad3,2"   : .iPad3,
            "iPad3,3"   : .iPad3,
            "iPad3,4"   : .iPad4,
            "iPad3,5"   : .iPad4,
            "iPad3,6"   : .iPad4,
            "iPad4,1"   : .iPadAir,
            "iPad4,2"   : .iPadAir,
            "iPad4,3"   : .iPadAir,
            "iPad5,3"   : .iPadAir2,
            "iPad5,4"   : .iPadAir2,
            "iPad6,11"  : .iPad5, //aka iPad 2017
            "iPad6,12"  : .iPad5,
            "iPad7,5"   : .iPad6, //aka iPad 2018
            "iPad7,6"   : .iPad6,
            //iPad mini
            "iPad2,5"   : .iPadMini,
            "iPad2,6"   : .iPadMini,
            "iPad2,7"   : .iPadMini,
            "iPad4,4"   : .iPadMini2,
            "iPad4,5"   : .iPadMini2,
            "iPad4,6"   : .iPadMini2,
            "iPad4,7"   : .iPadMini3,
            "iPad4,8"   : .iPadMini3,
            "iPad4,9"   : .iPadMini3,
            "iPad5,1"   : .iPadMini4,
            "iPad5,2"   : .iPadMini4,
            //iPad pro
            "iPad6,3"   : .iPadPro9_7,
            "iPad6,4"   : .iPadPro9_7,
            "iPad7,3"   : .iPadPro10_5,
            "iPad7,4"   : .iPadPro10_5,
            "iPad6,7"   : .iPadPro12_9,
            "iPad6,8"   : .iPadPro12_9,
            "iPad7,1"   : .iPadPro2_12_9,
            "iPad7,2"   : .iPadPro2_12_9,
            //iPhone
            "iPhone3,1" : .iPhone4,
            "iPhone3,2" : .iPhone4,
            "iPhone3,3" : .iPhone4,
            "iPhone4,1" : .iPhone4S,
            "iPhone5,1" : .iPhone5,
            "iPhone5,2" : .iPhone5,
            "iPhone5,3" : .iPhone5C,
            "iPhone5,4" : .iPhone5C,
            "iPhone6,1" : .iPhone5S,
            "iPhone6,2" : .iPhone5S,
            "iPhone7,1" : .iPhone6plus,
            "iPhone7,2" : .iPhone6,
            "iPhone8,1" : .iPhone6S,
            "iPhone8,2" : .iPhone6Splus,
            "iPhone8,4" : .iPhoneSE,
            "iPhone9,1" : .iPhone7,
            "iPhone9,3" : .iPhone7,
            "iPhone9,2" : .iPhone7plus,
            "iPhone9,4" : .iPhone7plus,
            "iPhone10,1" : .iPhone8,
            "iPhone10,4" : .iPhone8,
            "iPhone10,2" : .iPhone8plus,
            "iPhone10,5" : .iPhone8plus,
            "iPhone10,3" : .iPhoneX,
            "iPhone10,6" : .iPhoneX,
            "iPhone11,2" : .iPhoneXS,
            "iPhone11,4" : .iPhoneXSMax,
            "iPhone11,6" : .iPhoneXSMax,
            "iPhone11,8" : .iPhoneXR,
            //AppleTV
            "AppleTV5,3" : .AppleTV,
            "AppleTV6,2" : .AppleTV_4K
        ]

        if let model = modelMap[String.init(validatingUTF8: modelCode!)!] {
            if model == .simulator {
                if let simModelCode = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] {
                    if let simModel = modelMap[String.init(validatingUTF8: simModelCode)!] {
                        return simModel
                    }
                }
            }
            return model
        }
        return DeviceModel.unrecognized
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason at all to determine the type of iPhone. Simply base the cell height on the height of the view controller's view or the height of the table view.

Comment: I know. I gave him options, other than this, did I not?

Comment: Yeah but 90% of your answer is dedicated to using an inappropriate solution. Expand your answer showing just the proper options.